# Is there any way get the customer chat window in the same window. rather it open in different window .like i want like live agent popup

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent

I want customer chat in the same window rather it open in new window .I don't want to open in separate window it will happen in same window . like popup chat window

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the chat button onclick method by adding ", 'mywindow'" in this line:

```
           liveagent.startChatWithWindow('XXXX0000000XXXX', 'mywindow');
```

and add "window.name = "mywindow";" in the deployment like this:

```
   src="https://xxxx.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/33.0/deployment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.name = "mywindow";
        liveagent.init('https://xxxx.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', 'xxxx0000000xxxx', '00D40000000xxxx');
    </script>
```